# Strange "Freeze"

Tags: c++, box2d, codeblocks, sfml, freeze

When I compile and run application, for example this source code (from tutorial, I had to fix this code, ex. big letters in names of methods):

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>

/** We need this to easily convert between pixel and real-world coordinates*/
static const float SCALE = 30.f;

/** Create the base for the boxes to land */
void CreateGround(b2World& World, float X, float Y);

/** Create the boxes */
void CreateBox(b2World& World, int MouseX, int MouseY);

int main()
{
    /** Prepare the window */
    sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Test");
    Window.SetFramerateLimit(60);

    /** Prepare the world */
    b2Vec2 Gravity(0.f, 9.8f);
    b2World World(Gravity);
    CreateGround(World, 400.f, 500.f);

    /** Prepare textures */
    sf::Texture GroundTexture;
    sf::Texture BoxTexture;
    GroundTexture.LoadFromFile("ground.png");
    BoxTexture.LoadFromFile("box.png");

    while (Window.IsOpened())
    {
        if (sf::Mouse::IsButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
        {
            int MouseX = sf::Mouse::GetPosition(Window).x;
            int MouseY = sf::Mouse::GetPosition(Window).y;
            CreateBox(World, MouseX, MouseY);
        }
        World.Step(1/60.f, 8, 3);

        Window.Clear(sf::Color::White);
        int BodyCount = 0;
        for (b2Body* BodyIterator = World.GetBodyList(); BodyIterator != 0; BodyIterator = BodyIterator->GetNext())
        {
            if (BodyIterator->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody)
            {
                sf::Sprite Sprite;
                Sprite.SetTexture(BoxTexture);
                Sprite.SetOrigin(16.f, 16.f);
                Sprite.SetPosition(SCALE * BodyIterator->GetPosition().x, SCALE * BodyIterator->GetPosition().y);
                Sprite.SetRotation(BodyIterator->GetAngle() * 180/b2_pi);
                Window.Draw(Sprite);
                ++BodyCount;
            }
            else
            {
                sf::Sprite GroundSprite;
                GroundSprite.SetTexture(GroundTexture);
                GroundSprite.SetOrigin(400.f, 8.f);
                GroundSprite.SetPosition(BodyIterator->GetPosition().x * SCALE, BodyIterator->GetPosition().y * SCALE);
                GroundSprite.SetRotation(180/b2_pi * BodyIterator->GetAngle());
                Window.Draw(GroundSprite);
            }
        }
        Window.Display();
    }

    return 0;
}

void CreateBox(b2World& World, int MouseX, int MouseY)
{
    b2BodyDef BodyDef;
    BodyDef.position = b2Vec2(MouseX/SCALE, MouseY/SCALE);
    BodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    b2Body* Body = World.CreateBody(&BodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape Shape;
    Shape.SetAsBox((32.f/2)/SCALE, (32.f/2)/SCALE);
    b2FixtureDef FixtureDef;
    FixtureDef.density = 1.f;
    FixtureDef.friction = 0.7f;
    FixtureDef.shape = &Shape;
    Body->CreateFixture(&FixtureDef);
}

void CreateGround(b2World& World, float X, float Y)
{
    b2BodyDef BodyDef;
    BodyDef.position = b2Vec2(X/SCALE, Y/SCALE);
    BodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
    b2Body* Body = World.CreateBody(&BodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape Shape;
    Shape.SetAsBox((800.f/2)/SCALE, (16.f/2)/SCALE);
    b2FixtureDef FixtureDef;
    FixtureDef.density = 0.f;
    FixtureDef.shape = &Shape;
    Body->CreateFixture(&FixtureDef);
}
```

My application is "not responding" after few seconds. The window turns to grey but, everything works! Objects are moving and all interactions are working. What is the problem?

Comment: Recommendation: Put the code in the question not in a link. You are much more likely to get an answer and if you do, the pasted code is much more likely to last long enough for the answer to make sense.

Comment: Probably fixed. Dont know why but event loop solved this problem :)